# VS Code: Shortcut to select or remove Block Comment with no text selected

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know there is a shortcut for comment and uncomment code block (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>), but is there a way to quickly select (or even remove without select) block comment without using mouse or keyboard to select and press the delete/backspace button? For example:

```
/* 
This is a large block of code with at least 50 lines of code!
   :
   :
*/
```

Is there a keyboard shortcut where I can place my cursor **anywhere in the block comment** and remove it in just a few keystrokes? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried hold `ctrl` +`/` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a macro to do this pretty easily.

First, use the excellent [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by) extension (@rioV8) to select the text between and including the block comment markers `/*` and `*/`.  Put his into your settings:

```
"selectby.regexes": {

  "BlockCommentSelect": {
    "backward": "\/\\*",
    "forward": "\\*\/",
    "forwardInclude": true,
    "backwardInclude": true,
    "showSelection": true
  }
},
```

You can use that with a keybinding like:

```
{
  "key": "alt+s",           // whatever keybinding you wish
  "command": "selectby.regex",
  "args": ["BlockCommentSelect"],
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
```

You could stop here and use your keybinding to select the text and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to toggle off the block comment.

Or you could add the `selectby.regex1` to a macro and do it the selection and toggling off in one step.  Here using the macro extension [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) put this into your settings as well as the above `selectby.regexes` setting:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [

 {
  "command": "multiCommand.BlockCommentOff",
  "sequence": [
    { 
      "command": "selectby.regex",
      "args": ["BlockCommentSelect"] 
    },
    "editor.action.blockComment"
  ]
},
]
```

and then a keybinding to trigger that macro (in your keybindings.json):

```
{
  "key": "shift+alt+A",    // trigger the macro with whatever keybinding if you wish
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.BlockCommentOff" },
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorHasSelection"
},
```

Here I used <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to trigger the macro.  And I used the `when` clause `!editorHasSelection` because if you have a selection maybe you want to block comment only that selection (inside another block comment!!).

Demos: (1) Just the first method where `selectby` selects your text and you manually toggle it off, and then (2) using the macro version to do it in one step.

[image: block toggle from within the block]

Comment: Whoa! Sounds cool! Let me try it out and get back to you! Thank you so much!

Comment: And thanks for the refinement of my question title, that's much clearer and more precise!

Comment: I improved it slightly by using a named `selectby.BlockCommentSelect` rather than a numbered `selectby` command.  Just more descriptive and doesn't use up one of the available numbered commands.

Comment: Thanks Mark! Although I still have no time to play it out, I'm convinced that your solution should work as I expected it to be (based on your given GIF)! I'll come back to you again once I managed to try it out, thanks again!

Comment: Sorry for the wait, just have time to revisit your code -- It works like a champ! Thanks! :D