# How to create a keybind which comments current region of code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode, there is a native keybind to *fold* the current region of code without having to select it. But is there a native keybind to *comment* the current region without having to select it? If not, how would I create a custom keybind to do that?

Comment: you can use `Multi Command` to combine the selection of a region and commenting the selection and bind this new command to a key combo

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61414740/836330 for example.

Comment: @Mark that link explains how to create a keybind to select (and delete) text that is already wrapped in a block comment. That's not my situation.